# Find table entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a master table (tblVisit) on each visit someone marks down whether they found a specific item  or action point.

If for example they found a health and safety issue 3 times within any 12 week period how can I write a query to that effect?

Data Looks Like this:

> ```
> VisitID | DateServiceStart | VisitActivityRef |
> 111 | 01/01/2013 | 1
> 222 | 01/02/2013 | 1
> 333 | 06/02/2013 | 2
> 444 | 23/02/2013 | 1
> 555 | 18/03/2013 | 2
> ```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you know what a health and safety issue is?  Are you looking for a given 12-week period or to find the 12-week period where this might be true?

Comment: VisitActivityRef is linked to a lookup table which contains "Health and Safety Issue". so for this example VisitActivityRef = 1 is health and safety

Comment: . . That's nice.  I think you should revise your question with the appropriate information for answering it.  You can also include sample data and the results that you would like to get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LAG`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to get previous rows

So in your instance, compare the last but one date

```
 LAG (DateServiceStart, 2, null) OVER 
     (PARTITION BY VisitActivityRef ORDER BY DateServiceStart)
```

to the current row date, and find the difference using `DATEDIFF`